# Disabling 'Search' setting of a custom list

Tags: 2013, list, search, settings

I am working on `SP2013`. In every list, in the advanced settings, I find the option `Should items of this list be displayed in search results`.

Can't find an exact explanation to it, neither on SP itself, nor looking on the web.
Could someone tell me more about it?

In fact I'm wondering if this setting disables also the search in the lists (in every `AllItems.aspx` there is by default the searchbox) or only in a general search.

Comment: What are your findings thusfar when you tried the option?

Comment: Actually i did not try, since i don't have a test environment.

Comment: You can savely test this in production by creating an extra list with one item. If this is not allowed in production then the more reason to create a testenvironment. Playing with SharePoint is the best (and I say only) way to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling this option means that SharePoint will not crawl the items in the list and they will not come up in a general search, as you say.

In my experience, it *does* impact searching within the list, as well. The search box at the top of the list will still be visible, but if you enter a keyword and hit enter, you will receive the message "Your search returned no results."

Items in SharePoint need to be crawled for any search box to work. So, if you have disabled that functionality, the search box on the site and the search box at the top of the list will not return results from that list.

To hide the search box at the top of the list, edit the page, then edit the web part. In the web part properties menu, under miscellaneous, uncheck "Display search box." Click OK to save your changes on the web part and stop editing to save your changes on the page. The search box at the top of the list should now be hidden.

Comment: After reading your answer i did some tries. I disabled the search for a list...the search box inside the list still work partially: if i search for a "normal" field it works, if i search for data (e.g 'July') it doesn't find them....

Comment: As you said...it DOES affect all seraches!

Answer (score 1):

If disabled, this option prevents items from that particular list items to be crawled and displayed in "general" search. But it does not affect searching "inside" the list.